# Attribute relationships in Cube/Tabular model

Tags: powerbi, ssas, olap, cube

I was wondering what some of the more common attribute relationship 'patterns' might be in various setups. The two most common ones I can think of are:

- `Geography`: something like Continent > Country > State > City > ...
- `Time`: something like Year > Quarter > Month > Day > ...

What are some of the other patterns/groupings that are commonly used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization,
Product,
GL Code,
I always point people at [Wand](https://www.wandinc.com/), they sell taxonomies, and they are good at their stuff

Comment: thanks -- I'll take a look at that site. Could you briefly give a hierarchy for each of the above three? For example, I'm assuming Product might be something like Department > Product Category > Product (?).

Comment: Just remember that good fact tables are flat with a star schema, no hierarchy or snowflake, just the dimensions

Comment: I see, why is star preferred over snowflake? Do you have a link or so that I can read up a bit more about creating good fact tables, etc. ?

Comment: I always recommend the Kimball Group Reader, get it on Kindle, spend a few months browsing it, it's a great bed-time read. Then you can astound people with the depth of your knowledge :-)

Comment: thanks, I'm pretty new to this. Would you recommend that over the 
The Data Warehouse Toolkit as a first book to start with?

Comment: You might find the reader a little more digestible.  It's a collection of articles, easier for a start, Ralph gets a bit philosophical and you'll find yourself nodding in agreement. Get samples of both from Kindle that should tell you which one suits you best